# What does the ideal norm of matrix elements really mean?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, normed-spaces

Say we have a number field $K$ (specifically, an imaginary quadratic field) and a $2\times2$ matrix $\sigma=\pmatrix{a&c\\b&d}$ with elements $a,b,c,d\in\mathcal O_k$, the ring of integers of $K$. Generally, what is the significance of the [norm of the ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm) in $\mathcal O_k$ generated by the matrix elements, written $N(a,b,c,d)$, to the matrix $\sigma$?

For example, does the norm give us information about the eigenvalues of $\sigma$? If we write the norm as $N(\sigma)$, is the norm of a product $N(\sigma\tau)$ related to $N(\sigma)$ and $N(\tau)$ in a useful way, maybe involving determinants as well? Is $N$ or its square root a *bona fide* [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)?

I ask because in [Vulakh (1994) "Reflections in extended Bianchi groups"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100071887), the extended Bianchi group is  represented by matrices for which $\det(\sigma)=\epsilon N(\sigma)$ where $\epsilon$ is a unit in $\mathcal O_k$. I don't really follow how one is led to write down that equation.

Comment: you and me both.  do you now have any understanding of this characterization of the extended bianchi group?  (i'd appreciate it.)

Comment: @yoyo Sorry, I don't have any progress to report on this. I actually haven't thought about it much since asking the question, although I have vague plans to pick it up again someday. I'll be very interested if we do get an answer!